# Fetch JSON response from API using php

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to fetch data from API, but no data returns.
I try the API request in postman and it's working but in my php code nothing gets returned.

```
$uri = 'https://example.com';

$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method'=>'POST', 
    'header'=>'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($uri, false, $context);

print $result;
```

or using curl

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

the error is

```
file_get_contents(https://example.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
```

Note: the response size in postman is 9.83, is this maybe an issue?

Comment: Are you saying that this rejects a bogus response? I don't see a problem with your code then, only the server side. What's in the server logs, both for working (postman) requests and those not working?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt server logs ```failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required```

Comment: Those are not servers, but clients! Anyhow, add additional info to the question above, not as comments here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I found this warning error after run ```tail -f php_error.log``` in the server. Also in postman console ```The console only shows bodies smaller than 10 KB inline.```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/tester.phtml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// In real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// Further processing ...
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the provided solution not working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved by add Content-Length: 0 in the header